# Overlap a button over a list (Ionic)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, overlap

I'm a beginner here. I want to put an add button over a list in ionic, but I can't understand if this is possible or not. Something like this

> https://developer.android.com/design/material/images/list_mail.png

Is it possible in ionic? How I can code it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `ion-fab` in ionic app over a list button like this,

```
<ion-fab right bottom>
    <button ion-fab color="dark" (click)="addList()"><ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></button>
</ion-fab>
```